# What is needed to support NTLM proxy in the Google Analytics Reporting module

Tags: google-analytics, log-messages, proxies

I applied patches to support proxy for the [Google Analytics Reporting](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics_reports) module. But as per [issue 1801996](https://www.drupal.org/node/1801996), it is confirmed that the proxy patch is not applicable for NTLM proxies.

Please advise how much effort will be required to change the code and what all files to be changed for this are. Or how can support for NTLM proxies be added to the module.